# I'm interested in learning Soundwaves/Fourier's analysis/Acoustics, but need a starting point.

Tags: education

I thought this would be a good place to ask, but if this is the wrong place please guide me to where I should ask.

I'm in my first semester of college and I realized that I want to study math more seriously.

I'm interested mainly in formulae and soundwaves. Right now, my degree choices revolve around psychoacoustics or acoustic engineering. And I want to understand things like Fourier's Transform and how things like overtones differ with substances and materials.

But the highest form of math I've taken is Intermediate Algebra, and I'm not sure what areas of math I should be studying to achieve my particular interests. Physics? Linear Algebra? Calculus?

If you guys could help me start my journey into the math world, I'd be so grateful.

Comment: Change your title to, “I’m interested in learning psychoacoustics/sound waves/Fourier analysis but need a starting point”. Or something like that